# How to run Redis on Docker using docker-compose.yml?

Tags: spring, docker, redis

Have found an official [Spring tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) about the application developing that uses Redis keystore is described but don't know almost nothing about Docker and don't really want to learn it. The app's source code contains `docker-compose.yml` file with multiple Redis oriented settings and Spring docs are say:

> There is a docker-compose.yml file in the source code in Github which
>   you can run really easily on the command line with docker-compose up.

But it seems to be not that easy and Docker docs are too complicated.

Have installed Docker and deployed Redis there:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
81cbeeb08153        redis               "docker-entrypoint.sh"   22 hours ago        Up 21 minutes       6379/tcp            Server
```

The docker-compose.yml

```
redis:
image: redis
ports:
  - "6379:6379"
```

What's next? How to import this in Docker Redis?

I'm trying to up Redis on the Windows machine to let my simple localhost app finally work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Docker Compose [installed](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)? If yes, just run `docker-compose up` - it will start redis image and make it listen on a correct port.

Alternatively, you will have to start redis manually and correctly expose specified port.

Comment: Yeah it's installed. But where have I place the `docker-compose.yml` before I run this command?

Comment: Usually, it's in project's root directory so you can start something right after you pull it.
In your specific case, `docker-compose.yml` does not rely on other files so it's fine anywhere it is. You `cd` to that directory and then `docker-compose up`.
If you've run redis image without docker-compose on the same port you'd need to stop it to avoid conflict.